# How to mange multiple divs' height and each div's height depends on another?

Tags: html, css, angular

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-z32zec ,in this case, The container area's height is self adapt to the screen's height. The header area is always in the top of the container, and it's height is unknown. The bottom area is always in the bottom of the container, but it's height is a constant. The content area height depends on the header area, so it may have blank if the sum height of the three area is smaller than the screen height. When header area height increase, the content area height decrease. Than means the bottom area height and the sum height never change.
I wanna know if there's anyone knows how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your stackblitz demo, I think this is what you want (just let me know if it's not): [Stackbliz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-stackblitz-58002917?file=src/app/app.component.scss)

```html
<div class="container">

    <div class="header">
        This header area height is unknown, maybe increase or decrease. asdfasd
    </div>

    <div class="content">
        This content area height depends on 'header area' height. It may have blank if the sum height of three areas is smaller than
        the screen height. When header area height increase, this area height decrease.
    </div>

    <div class="bottom-div">
        This area is always in the bottom of the container, and the container's height is the screen's height. The bottom area's
        height is a constant.
    </div>

</div>
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction:column;

  &>* {
    flex-shrink: 0;
  }

  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 100vh;
}


.header {
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.content {
  flex: 1;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.bottom-div {
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it's kind of different. What I want is: when the header height increase, the content height decrease, not moving down. And all the blank should be in the content area.

Comment: Ok, it's easy to fix it. Take a look again at the Stackbliz demo (updated).

Comment: Thanks, that's waht I wanted. And sorry for that I'm new to css